# can t run with os.system a script placed in the folder anaconda/scripts

Tags: python, anaconda

my package generates scripts placed in the folder aanconda/script automatically during the installation

these scripts are really simple and use argparse for managing script arguments.
here is an example

```
if __name__ == "__main__":


    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='CGM1-pipeline')
    parser.add_argument('-uf','--userFile', type=str, help='userSettings', default="CGM1.userSettings")
    parser.add_argument('-ef','--expertFile', type=str, help='Local expert settings', default=None)

    args = parser.parse_args()
        #print args

        # ---- main script -----
    try:
        print args
        #main(args)


    except Exception, errormsg:
        print "Script errored!"
        print "Error message: %s" % errormsg
        traceback.print_exc()
        print "Press return to exit.."
        raw_input()
```

everything work fine from Powershell. I can change my argument like that

```
script.py -uf="toto.c3d"
```

It s perfect, 
except, i d like to run it from a python script with either os.system or subprocess.

if i do

```
import os
os.system("script.py -uf=toto.c3d")
```

this command doesn t consider my argument uf. It keeps the default value.

that works if i do

```
import os
os.system("python C:/Anaconda/Scripts/script.py -uf=toto.c3d")
```

why does not  the first syntax   work ?

regards

Comment: _`os.system("script.py -uf=toto.c3d")`_ Your script doesn't seem to start with a shebang line.  Is it marked as executable?  What program is Powershell configured to use for `.py` files?

Comment: py extension is correctly associated to python.exe. 
Since Script.py is in anaconda/scripts, i can run it from powershell. it is executable.